# python3 multiprocessing Processでプロセスが平行で動いてくれません

Tags: python, python3, python-multiprocessing

ミュージックプレイヤーを個人で作っています。
言語：Python 3.7
環境：VS2017 community
OS：windows 10 64bit
cpu：core i3

プログラミング初心者です。頓珍漢なことを書いていたら指摘してください。
音楽CD（wav,16bit,44100Hz）からwavファイルを読み込んでギャップレス再生できるように
するために、numpyの配列で全曲を連結することをしております。
「読み込み＆連結」の時間を短縮するために、CDアルバム内の14曲のファイルを
２つのリストに振り分けてから「wavファイルデータの読み込み＆連結」を
２プロセスで平行処理したいと思っています。

詳細：
リスト内データサイズは300MBあたりを境界として２つのリスト「self.fl1ba,self.fl1bb」に
分割しております。
そのあと、「self.fl1ba」と「self.fl1bb」からmultiprocessingのProcessクラスを
使用して平行処理で時間短縮をしようとしています。
しかし、Processを設定して「start()」しても平行処理になってくれません。
vstack1 = mp.Process(target=stack.fl_vstack1())
「.fl_vstack1()」の「()」を削除すると動かなくなります。
Poolクラスでも試しましたが、調べてみると、Poolの場合、「map」を使うでnumpy.arrayの
２次元配列は処理できないようでした。

wavファイル読み込みモジュールはpysoundfileを使用しています。
data,fs=soundfile.read(ファイル,dtype='int16')で２次元データ配列(data)と
サンプリング周波数(fs)が得られます。
再生はsounddeviceモジュールを使用。コードをここに入力

ファイル読み込み＆連結を平行処理する方法をご教示ください。
よろしくお願いします。

補足1：
nekketsuuuさん、回答ありがとうございます。
回答いただいたソースではうまく5(s)程度で処理してくれまた。
しかし、私のコードでは関数が「def fl_vstack1(self)」となっているためか、「args=()」とすることで「self」が「None」に置き換わってしまった気がします。実行すると、関数の
「def fl_vstack1(self)」は実行されませんでした。関数内の処理そのものが動いていないと思います。というのも、array配列「self.sumdata1」を初期化したとき代入した[0,0]を関数内で削除しているのですが、それも実行されていなかったためです。Processクラスでは「self」を使えないのでしょうか？ご教示よろしくお願いします。

補足2：
metropolisさん、コメントありがとうございます。
ご指摘どおりログをとってみました。なんと！「vstack1」と「vstack2」のプロセスは動作しておりました。別の問題で最後まで実行されていないことが分かりました。
別の問題とは、２プロセスの「vstack1」と「vstack2」で処理した値が次の２プロセスの「tvstack1」と「tvstack2」へ受け渡されていないことです。「self」に格納されるものと思っていたのですが、違うことが分かりました。「Pipe」や「Queue」というものを使えばいいのか、これから調べます。

```
import os
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
import time
import soundfile as sf
import sounddevice as sd

class Fileread():

    def __init__(self):
                
    ### ディレクトリから「wavファイル」のみをself.fl1bに取得 ###
        os.chdir("C:/Users/Public/Music/Music Center/Shared/Music/Aerosmith/Unplugged 1990 (Live)")
        dir1 = os.getcwd()
        self.dir2 = os.listdir(dir1)
        
        self.fl1b = []
        for j in self.dir2:

            base,ext = os.path.splitext(j)

            if ext == '.wav':

                self.fl1b.append(j)
        
        self.sumflsize1 = 0
        self.sumflsize2 = 0
        
        self.fl1c1 = []
        self.fl1c2 = []

        self.fl1ba = []        
        self.fl1bb = []

        self.sumdata1 = np.array([0,0],dtype='int16')
        self.sumdata2 = np.array([0,0],dtype='int16')

        self.fl1t1 = []
        
        self.fs = 0




        ### リスト内ファイルを２分割するメソッドを格納 ###
        self.split_album()

    ### リストとして取得したファイルを別の２つのリストに２分割 ###
    def split_album(self):

        flsize = []
        
        ### アルバム内の各ファイルサイズを取得 ###
        for h in self.fl1b:

            flsize.append(os.path.getsize(h))


        ### アルバム内ファイルをリスト「self.fl1ba」と「self.fl1bb」に格納 ###
        list_len = len(self.fl1b)
        
        for d in range(list_len):

            self.sumflsize1 += flsize[d]
            self.fl1ba.append(self.fl1b[d])
                
            if self.sumflsize1 > 300000000:

                break

        for q in range(list_len):

            if q <= d:
                pass
            else:
                self.sumflsize2 += flsize[q]
                self.fl1bb.append(self.fl1b[q])

    ### リスト「self.fl1ba」内の各ファイルを'int16'で取得し、「self.sumdata1」に追加 ###
    def fl_vstack1(self):
        
        list_len1 = len(self.fl1ba)

        for k in range(list_len1):

            data,fs = sf.read(self.fl1ba[k],dtype='int16')
            self.fs = fs  ### fsはサンプリング周波数 ###
            
            frame_num = len(data)
            self.fl1c1.append(frame_num) ### 各ファイルの再生時間を算出するためにフレーム数を取得 ###
            self.sumdata1 = np.vstack((self.sumdata1,data)) ### 「self.sumdata1」にwavファイルから読み込んだdataを追加 ###


        self.sumdata1 = np.delete(self.sumdata1,0,0)

    ### 「fl_vstack1」と同じことを「self.fl1bb」内のファイルについても実行 ###
    def fl_vstack2(self):

        list_len2 = len(self.fl1bb)

        if list_len2 > 0:  ### リスト「self.fl1bb」にファイルが存在する場合 ###

            for k in range(list_len2):

                data,fs = sf.read(self.fl1bb[k],dtype='int16')

                frame_num = len(data)
                self.fl1c2.append(frame_num)
                self.sumdata2 = np.vstack((self.sumdata2,data))

            self.sumdata2 = np.delete(self.sumdata2,0,0)            

        else:
            pass

    ### 「fl_vstack1」と「fl_vstack2」で積み上げたデータを連結 ###
    def sum_stack(self):

        self.sumdata1 = np.vstack((self.sumdata1,self.sumdata2))
        
    ### 各ファイル（曲）の演奏時間を算出 ###
    def sum_time(self):

        self.fl1c1 = self.fl1c1 + self.fl1c2
        self.fl1t1 = list(map(lambda x: x/self.fs/60,self.fl1c1))

    ### 連結したファイルを再生（ギャップレス再生） ###
    def sdplay(self):

        sd.play(self.sumdata1,self.fs)
        status = sd.wait()


if __name__=='__main__':

    stack = Fileread()

    ### プロセス「vstack1」と「vstack2」が平行して動かない ###
    ### vstack1.start()ではなく下記プロセス設定時に処理が始まっているようです ###
    ### 「stack.fl_vstack1()」の「()」を削除して実行すると処理してくれません ###
    start1 = time.time()
    vstack1 = mp.Process(target=stack.fl_vstack1())
    print('stack1:',time.time() - start1)
    vstack2 = mp.Process(target=stack.fl_vstack2())
    print('stack2:',time.time() - start1)
    

    vstack1.start()
    vstack2.start()
    
    vstack1.join()
    vstack2.join()

    tvstack1 = mp.Process(target=stack.sum_stack())
    tvstack2 = mp.Process(target=stack.sum_time())
    tvstack1.start()
    tvstack2.start()
    tvstack1.join()
    tvstack2.join()


    tvstack3 = mp.Process(target=stack.sdplay())
    tvstack3.start()
```

Comment: ログを取ってみてはどうでしょうか。具体的には `start1 = time.time()` の直前に、`mp.log_to_stderr(logging.DEBUG)` を追加して、logging モジュールをインポートしておきます(`import logging`)。

Answer (score 5, accepted):

質問者さんがおっしゃる通り、現在のコードでは以下の行で `fl_vstack1` 関数が呼び出されてしまっています。

```
vstack1 = mp.Process(target=stack.fl_vstack1())
```

この行では引数 `target` に `stack.fl_vstack1()` を代入していますが、これは関数呼び出しの構文なので関数呼び出しが起こり、その**返り値**が `target` に代入されています。本当に代入したかったのは `fl_vstack1` という **関数そのもの** であったはずです。

こうする代わりに、下のように `args` を長さ 0 のタプルとして指定してください。つまり、`target` に関数自体を、`args` に引数を指定している形です。この使い方は [`multiprocessing.Process` のドキュメント](https://docs.python.org/ja/3/library/multiprocessing.html#the-process-class)に書かれています。

```
vstack1 = mp.Process(target=stack.fl_vstack1, args=())
```

こうすると上手くいくことは質問文中の長いソースコードだと分かりにくいかもしれません。この部分の動作だけ確認できるサンプルコードを用意しましたので、必要に応じてご利用ください。

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import time

def f():
    time.sleep(5)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    process1 = mp.Process(target=f, args=())
    process2 = mp.Process(target=f, args=())

    # 並列に実行されているなら、"Start!" から "Finish!" まで大体 5 秒のはずです。
    print("Start!")
    process1.start()
    process2.start()

    process1.join()
    process2.join()
    print("Finish!")
```